# How to compose Grails validation messages?

Tags: validation, grails, error-handling

I have a simple domain entity:

```
package shoesshop

class Brand {

    String name
    String description
    String logoImageURL

    static constraints = {
        name(blank: false)
        logoImageURL(nullable: true)
    }
}
```

When I try to save a new brand with null value as its name, I want to render a message which says that 'Name must be specified'.

I tryied to add a property to `messages.properties`:

```
brand.name.nullable=Brand name must be specified
```

But it's not picked up automatically. How should I retrieve it from there? 
I looked at `brand.errors` and it contains just a default message

`Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null`.

It also contains a set of error codes, one of which is `brand.name.nullable`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried?:

```
if(brand.name==null)
{
    flash.message = message(code: 'brand.name.nullable',default:'Brand name must be specified.');
    render(view: "create", model: [brand:brand])
    return
}
```

You can try to change the message (don't know how this will perform with your entire app)  of "default.null.message" to

```
{1} {0} must be specified
```

Answer (score 1):

It's strange to me that the nullable error message is showing up when you don't have the nullable constraint.  In the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/blank.html) for blank and nullable it clearly shows that `nullable` is different than `blank` and have separate messages.

Try

```
brand.name.blank
```

I also seem to have to add the `.error` to get things to work correctly:

```
brand.name.blank.error or brand.name.nullable.error
```

Comment: it's because that when user submit from the web, "name" would be a blank string instead of null.

Comment: That's what I'm saying - he is not getting the blank error message like he should when the user submits with a blank field.  He is getting the nullable message.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Grails 2.2.3. For me it works when I am using

```
brands.name.blank=The name cannot be empty
```

Now if I refresh the page ".../appname/controllername/save" after getting this error, I get

```
Property [name] of class [class ...] cannot be null
```

This message can be changed with

```
brands.name.nullable=The name cannot be null (do not refresh the page!!!)
```